# ¿Cómo puedo importar un componente de vue dentro de otro?

Tags: vue.js

Estoy iniciando en `Vue Js` y me gustaría algo de orientación si es posible, quiero saber si es posible importar un componente dentro de otro, hasta donde eh visto si es posible, pero no logro hacerlo.

Los pasos de instalación de `Vue Js` que realicé son los siguientes:

```
# install vue-cli
$ npm install --global vue-cli
# create a new project using the "webpack" template
$ vue init webpack my-project
# install dependencies and go!
$ cd my-project
$ npm install
$ npm run dev
```

Estoy trabajando con `Webpack` siguiendo los pasos de la [documentación](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#CLI).

Agregue el repositorio en [GitHub](https://github.com/Andresferreira3191/VueJS) para que lo puedan ver y mirar que estoy haciendo mal, de igual forma dejo el código a continuación:

**HelloWorld.vue:**

```
<template>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
            <hr/>
        </div>
        <my-component></my-component>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import Paises from '@/components/Paises'

    export default {
        name: 'HelloWorld',
        component:{
            'my-component': Paises
        },
        data () {
            return {
                msg: 'Example of components with Vue.js App'
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>

</style>
```

**Paises.vue:**

```
<template>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h1>{{ msg_paises }}</h1>
            <hr/>
            Test
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Paises',
  data () {
    return {
      msg_paises: 'Component #1'
    }
  }
}
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>

</style>
```

El error que me marca la consola dice:

> [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element:  - did you register
> the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to
> provide the "name" option.
>
> found in
>
> --->  at src\components\HelloWorld.vue
>  at src\App.vue

El mensaje de error considero que es claro pero sigo sin identificar que tendria que hacer entonces.

Revise la [Documentación de componentes](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html)  y también este [ejemplo](https://www.uno-de-piera.com/desarrollo-agil-slots-vue-js-2/) pero no doy para lograrlo.

Comment: Para registrar un componente localmente debes usar `components` en vez de `component`. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Local-Registration

Comment: -_-! Gracias @JoseHermosillaRodrigo pequeños detalles que se le pasan a uno cuando se esta aprendiendo, una ultima consulta, podrías decirme como enviar información a dicho componente, también ponlo como respuesta para calificarla ya que funciono.

Comment: a lo ultimo de enviar información ya no hace falta ya pude con `props`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes registrar tu componente desde la propiedad `components`:

```js
const ComponenteHijo = {
  template: '<p>Soy el Hijo</p>'
}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    ComponenteHijo
  },
  template: '<componente-hijo></componente-hijo>'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://vuejs.org/js/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

[`DOC`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Local-Registration)